How to load Available payment methods of custom page same as checkout does?
I'm creating a module which is called post-purchase upsell.
In this module, as a final step, I need to charge an amount.
For that, I need to load all available payment methods the same as checkout does https://prnt.sc/vsFunEkjlN_i. So, I can use direct payment services on the custom module page.

You can use the checkout session at that page you will get the all you want.
This class:
Magento\Checkout\Model\Session


Thank you for your response, but it is not relevant to my question.

I do this the same and my all payment methods are loading!

Can you please share your code?

You can get active payment method list from this code.
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Payment\Model\Config;

class Paymentmethodlist extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject 
    implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $_paymentModelConfig;
    
    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface
     * @param Config               $paymentModelConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface,
        Config $paymentModelConfig
    ) {
        $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
        $this->_paymentModelConfig = $paymentModelConfig;
    }
 
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $payments = $this->_paymentModelConfig->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = array();
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
            $paymentTitle = $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface
                ->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                'label' => $paymentTitle,
                'value' => $paymentCode
            );
        }
        return $methods;
    }
}

Now this class return lists, from that you need to show as radio list of your custom page.
